# Can I Use Rainwater to Generate Reverse Osmosis Water for Fish?

Tags: aquarium, fish

I currently use half Reverse Osmosis (RO) water, half tap water & dechlorinator for my aquariums (probably closer to 75/25) but it takes a lot of water to generate enough RO to do water changes every week. For each unit of RO I create, I throw away at least 2 units. I know that I could use it for other purposes (such as water plants etc) but I still have to pay for that water.

I live in the UK so there's no shortage of rainwater falling out of the sky. As I am removing the total dissolved solids and, I think, the bacteria, there should be no reason that I cannot generate RO water with rainwater that I can see.

**Can I safely make RO water using rainwater as the input and is my reasoning above correct?**

Comment: Not an answer, but have you considered put the discard water in toilet tank?  There should be a shut off valve on the line going to the toilet tank, turn it off when you get up in the morning (*before first use*). As waste RO water is generated fill the toilet tank with it.  If you have an older model toilet it probably holds 5 gallons (19 liters) even the newer ones use 1.6 gallons or 6 liters per flush.  This applies even if you do use rain water as your source supply. You might even use a two barrel solution, one for rain, one with an on demand pump for the toilet.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your pre filters too.

My RO/DI unit has a sediment filter -> carbon filter -> RO membrane -> DI resins.

If you have the carbon filter you should be ok filtering rain water through your RO unit.

Also keep in mind Ro filtering works if you have proper pressure: 60 PSI is best.

So you will need a booster pump for it.

This article might shed some more light on the bacteria removal (paragraph 5):
http://www.purewaterproducts.com/articles/carbon

Seems between carbon and the RO membrane you should be fine.

This seems like a good choice:
https://www.bulkreefsupply.com/brs-universal-carbon-block-filter-1-micron.html